# Reshape pandas dataframe with 3 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have the following code:

```
sentiments = ['He is good', 'He is bad', 'She love her', 'She is fine with it', 'I like going outside', 'Its okay']
positive = [1,0,1,0,1,0]
negative = [0,1,0,0,0,0]
neutral = [0,0,0,1,0,1]
neutral
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentiments':sentiments, 'Positives':positive, 'Negatives': negative, 'Neutrals':neutral})
df.head()
```

which creates this:

[image: df]

I want to have instead only 2 columns, 1 with sentiment and other with category and that should be that particular sentiment i.e. the result should be:

| Sentiment | Category |
| --- | --- |
| abc | positive |
| xmy | negative |
| poi | neutral |

Answer (score 0):

Try `.melt()`:

```py
x = df.melt("Sentiments", var_name="Category")
x = x[x.value != 0].drop(columns="value")
x["Category"] = x["Category"].str.replace(r"s$", "", regex=True)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
              Sentiments  Category
0             He is good  Positive
2           She love her  Positive
4   I like going outside  Positive
7              He is bad  Negative
15   She is fine with it   Neutral
17              Its okay   Neutral
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only going to be one column with the value 1 (i.e. dummies), try:

```
>>> df.set_index("Sentiments").idxmax(axis=1).rename("Category").reset_index()
             Sentiments   Category
0            He is good  Positives
1             He is bad  Negatives
2          She love her  Positives
3   She is fine with it   Neutrals
4  I like going outside  Positives
5              Its okay   Neutrals
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df = df.set_index('Sentiments').dot(df.columns[1:]).reset_index(name = 'Category')
```